# hierarchy property in graph database

Tags: database-design, neo4j, nosql, cypher, graph-databases

I'm starting to use neo4j.
In my graph database I've the nodes `Person` (look at "John" below), with the labels: `Name` (string), `Food` (positive integer). Each `Person` is connected with other `Person` through the relationship `isFriendTo`, that has a value.
I use the graph DB only to find the shortest weighted path between two person.

Also, every day I check every node in the graph, and if the food go under value of 100, I take some actions.

Now, after some improvements, the property `Food` is no more enough for my project. So I have to split this in three other more specific property (positive integer): `Vegetables`, `Meat` and `Cereals`. If the sum of both three go under 100, I've to take the same actions as before. 
My old situation was as "John", the only options to which I can evolve my design is to "Fred" or "Paul"?

[image]

In which way can I design this? Should I use in addition to neo4j something like MongoDB to represent hierarchy?

Removing the property Food and add the three new properties seems like a bad practices to me. I've to save elsewhere that this 3 means "food"... and what about if in the future will I add others types of foods? Where do I store the knowledge that the value 100 to check, must come from the sum of `Meat`, `Vegetables` and `Cereals`?
Having something like this, will solve my doubt because I can sum all items inside `food`:

```
{
  "name": "Lucas",
  "food": {
    "meat": 40,
    "vegetables": 30,
    "cereals": 0
  }
}
```

(I don't need to traverse the connections from `Food` and `Vegetables` to `Person`. Just need to check that the sum of Meat, Veg. and Cereals is lesser or greater 100.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are confusing the terms [label](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-labels) and [property](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/introduction/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-neo4j-properties).

According to your diagram, `Person` seems to be the *label* shared by all your nodes, and `Name/Food//Meat/Vegetables/Cererals` seem to be the names of node *properties*.

If my understanding is correct, then there are many approaches to handling multiple food type amounts, and getting a total per person. Below are a couple of examples.

1. Here is one approach. You could introduce the `Food` label for [unique](https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/3.4/cypher/schema/constraints/#query-constraint-unique-nodes) food type nodes:

   ```
   (:Food {type: 'Meat'}), (:Food {type: 'Vegetable'}), etc.
   ```

   and each `Person` node can have a `HAS_FOOD` relationship (with an `amount` property) to each relevant Food node (instead of storing the food type properties internally):

   ```
   (john:Person {Name: 'John'})-[:HAS_FOOD {amount: 140}]->(meat:Food {type: 'Meat'})
   ```

   With this data model, to find all `Person`s with more than 100 units of food:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person)-[r:HAS_FOOD]->()
   WITH p, SUM(r.amount) AS total
   WHERE total > 100
   RETURN p;
   ```
2. Here is another approach (which will likely result in faster searches). Since a  neo4j property cannot have a map value (contrary to what you show in the JSON near the bottom of your question), each `Person` node could have `amount` and `food` arrays, like this:

   ```
   (:Person {Name: 'Fred', amount: [50, 100], food: ['Meat','Vegetables']})
   ```

   With this data model, to find all `Person`s with more than 100 units of food:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person)
   WHERE REDUCE(s = 0, a IN p.amount | s + a) > 100
   RETURN p;
   ```

   [UPDATE]

   However, doing food processing (nice pun, here), with second approach can be more cumbersome and less efficient. For example, this is one way to get the amount of Meat for `Fred`:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person {Name: 'Fred'})
   RETURN [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(p.food)-1) WHERE p.food[i] = 'Meat' | p.amount[i]][0] AS meatAmt;
   ```

   And, to set the amount of Meat for `Fred` to 123:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person {Name: 'Fred'})
   SET p.amount = [i IN RANGE(0, SIZE(p.food)-1) | CASE WHEN p.food[i] = 'Meat' THEN 123 ELSE p.amount[i]];
   ```
3. So, here is a 3rd approach that solves your issue AND is much better for performing food processing. Each Person node could store food amounts directly as properties, like this:

   ```
   (:Person {Name: 'Fred', Meat: 50, Vegetables: 100, foodNames: ['Meat', 'Vegetables']})
   ```

   With this data model, the `foodNames` array allows you to iterate through the food properties by name. So, to find all Persons with more than 100 units of food:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person)
   WHERE REDUCE(s = 0, n IN p.foodNames | s + p[n]) > 100
   RETURN p;
   ```

   And, to get the amount of Meat for `Fred`:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person {Name: 'Fred'})
   RETURN p.Meat AS meatAmt;
   ```

   To set the amount of Meat for `Fred` to 123:

   ```
   MATCH (p:Person {Name: 'Fred'})
   SET p.Meat = 123;
   ```

Comment: Thanks! The second approach was what I was looking for, easy and fast. I already thought to the first solution, but I felt like adding unnecessary complexity because I don't need to traverse these kind of nodes.

Comment: How can I get the amount of Meat for Fred?

Comment: I have a much better 3rd approach. See my updated answer.

Comment: I like more this new solution. :) It's ok to repeat foodNames: ['Meat', 'Vegetables'] in every Person, or can I externalize it?

Comment: What do you mean by "externalize"?

Comment: Put it outside every single Person, so I must not repeat it every time. But don't mind, every Person can have different kind of food, so was just a bad idea. ^^'

Answer (score 0):

On Neo4j, labels are like tags, there is no technical hierarchy, and a node can has many labels.

But if you want to says that `Food` is the parent of `Vegetables`, `Meat` and `Cereals` from your business perspective, there is no prob. You will have a business/semantic hierarchy.

So from my POV, in your case I would only add the new labels on your nodes with the label `Food`

Comment: Food is not a node. In my first version of code was a label.

Comment: Sorry it was an abuse of language : `add the new labels on your nodes with the label Food`

Comment: Ok, so you mean that instead of my original idea of removing from the node Person, the label Food. For you is it better to keep it and have the labels: Food, Vegetables, Meat and Cereals?

Comment: I mean if you have node `carrot` this node should have the labels `Food` AND `Vegetable`

Comment: I edited my original post, maybe now it is more clear.