# Collections containing mixed types can not be stored in properties

Tags: neo4j, cypher, neo4j-python-driver

I am new to Neo4j, I am trying to create a node like so:

```
neo4_session.run("MERGE (t:Table {name: $name, columns: $columns}) ",
     name=table['table_name'], columns=[{'colname':'a'},{'colname':'b'},{'colname':'c'}])
```

Neo4j tells me this:

> neo4j.exceptions.CypherTypeError: Collections containing mixed types
>   can not be stored in properties.

Which means it only allows me to have a list:

```
neo4_session.run("MERGE (t:Table {name: $name, columns: $columns}) ",
     name=table['table_name'], columns=['a','b','c'])
```

However, each table node in my database will have different column names so I can't really have a list of properties...

Any advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should consider using a `:Column` node label instead of a list of columns in the `:Table` node.

This way you can model your graph like this:

```
CREATE (table:Table {name : 'Table 1'})
CREATE (columnA:Column {colname : 'a'})
CREATE (columnB:Column {colname : 'b', otherProp: 'Other value'})
CREATE (columnC:Column {colname : 'c'})
CREATE (table)-[:CONTAINS]->(columnA)
CREATE (table)-[:CONTAINS]->(columnB)
CREATE (table)-[:CONTAINS]->(columnC)
```

Resulting on:

[image: Sample data]

Also, this is a more "graphist" way to model your data.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest approach is to just directly store each column as a property:

```
CREATE (table:Table {name: 'Table 1', colName1: 'a', colName2: 'b', colName3: 'c'})
```

And, if you need to access the columns in column-order for some reason, you could have an array, say `colNames`, that stores the ordered column names:

```
CREATE (table:Table {
  name : 'Table 1',
  colName1: 'a', colName2: 'b', colName3: 'c',
  colNames: ['colName1', 'colName2', 'colName3']
})
```

*Also, see [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51023869/hierarchy-property-in-graph-database/51032359?noredirect=1#comment89075291_51032359) and the third approach I suggested in my answer.*

[UPDATE]

As indicated by @Tezra, the above `CREATE` clauses can be refined to just take a parameter whose value is a map dynamically generated by your code. For example, if this were passed as the `$data` parameter:

```
{
  name : 'Table 1',
  colName1: 'a', colName2: 'b', colName3: 'c',
  colNames: ['colName1', 'colName2', 'colName3']
}
```

then this `CREATE` clause would get the same results as my previous clause:

```
CREATE (table:Table $data)
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with the python-driver, but if it's similar to the java driver, can't he pass in the column-value map as a query param and just assign it to the node in the query? (Since they updated that the column names will be dynamic based on table)

Comment: @user2471214 here are the docs for using params in Cypher (https://neo4j.com/docs/developer-manual/current/cypher/syntax/parameters/)